How can I remove a snapped off screw in oven's side rail?
We have a Kenwood oven. It has screws which help hold the side rails in place. The screws are a bit rusty. As we went to take one out it then snapped off leaving the remaining threaded part in the oven. How do we remove this part, please? It is so small.

Pictures?  If they are very short screws, I might just drill a new hole close by, and leave the broken screw there.

What are "side rails" here?

Hard to tell without a photo, but these things come to mind:

Use a screw extractor to remove the screw stump.
Drill out the screw, then enlarge the screw hole, and tap it for a larger screw.
Make something else to hold the rails in place (this may involve drilling more screw holes).
Do nothing. Not applicable in all cases, but if the screw is redundant, this may be the best option.


A few suggestions adapted from ShunTool DYI website, https://shuntool.com/article/flat-head-screw-rusted-inside-oven, two of which echo mike-baranczak answer:

Use penetrating oil or WD-40 to loosen the screw remnant
Use pliers if there is enough of the screw remnant to grip
Screw removal kit
Drill out the screw

There are lots of details on each of these suggestions on the ShunTool website, including product suggestions for penetrating oil and screw removal kit, and tips for successful drilling out the screw.
